# Adding properties to AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS service that looks like this:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .factory('$myService', function () {    
    return {
      getName: function () {
        return 'Bill';
      },

      isAvailable: function () {
        return true;
      }
    };
  })
;
```

Is there a way to add properties? Currently, the service has function (aka `$myService.isAvailable()`). I'm curious, is there a way to have something like `$myService.someProperty`? If so, how? Or, does everything in a service have to be a function?

Thank you!

Comment: Please consider removing the `$` prefix if possible, it is reserved for anything built-in from angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the Revealing Module Pattern, you can easily encapsulate your data and expose only the properties/functions that you want in your public API:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .factory('$myService', function () {   
    var name = { name: 'John' };
    var phone = { phone: '555-5555'};
    var SSN = 123456789;
    var address = '5555 Rd Blvd.';
    var available = { isAvailable: false };

    return {
      getName: function () {
        return name;
      },

      isAvailable: function () {
        return available;
      }

      name: name,
      phone: phone,
      address: address
    };
  })
;
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the "Revealing Module Pattern". This approach allowed me to get through JSHint.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simply add a property in the returned object

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .factory('$myService', function () {    
    return {
      getName: function () {
        return 'Bill';
      },

      isAvailable: function () {
        return true;
      },

      someProperty: 'New Property'
    };
  });
```